# Java Decision, conditional statement with three branches?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am quite new to programming and would like to know how to set this:
if else java how to sets s to 1 if x is positive, to -1 if x is negative, and to 0 if X is zero?

```
if (x > 0) {
    System.out.println(s = 1);
} else if (x < 0) {
    System.out.println(s = -1);
} else if (x == 0) {
    System.out.println(s = 0);
}
```

Comment: Your last block could be an `else`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: In stead of printing, assign the new value to s: `s = <new value>;`.

Comment: When you print out println(s=1) your printing whether the action of assigning 1 to the variable s worked so you will get true. If you want to print out the value of s just use println(s)

Comment: Do you mean `s=(x>0 ? 1 : x < 0 ? -1 : 0)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. `System.out.println()` takes a `String` and prints it to the console. You need something that will print to the console.

```
int s=0;
if(x > 0) {
    s = 1;  
}
else if(x < 0) {
    s = -1;  
}

System.out.println("s=" + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
   if (x>0)
       {
           System.out.println(s=1);  
       }
       else if (x<0)
       {
           System.out.println(s=-1);  
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println(s=0);
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// If x is greater than 0 then s = 1
if (x>0)
{
    System.out.println(s=1);  
}
// Else if x is less than 0 then s = -1
else if (x<0)
{
    System.out.println(s=-1);  
}
// Else it MUST be 0 so s = 0
else
{
    System.out.println(s=0);
}
```

Comment: This code snippet wouldn't even work/solve the problem at hand. Please proofread your code before posting it.